# Given an equilateral triangle $ABC$ and $P$ is any point inside the triangle such that $PA^2 = PB^2 + PC^2$. Then what is angle $BPC$?

Tags: geometry, triangles, angle

I could only come up with a rough diagram but I couldn't move any further.

Comment: Take $P$ on the altitude from $A$ and set $x=PA$. Take also $1$ as length of a side. Can you find $x$?

Comment: You could use the 'inverse' pythagorean theorem.

Comment: @BGasull Can you explain how inverse pythagorean theorem can be helpful as we don't know that measure of any of the sides of the triangle?

Comment: @AJ A triangle such the pythagorean equality holds is a right triangle. So you can form a right triangle with the segments PA, PB and PC.

Answer (score 1):

Let $Q$ be the image of $P$ by the $60$-degree rotation that turns $A$ to $B$. Then $\triangle ACP = \triangle BCQ$, and we have $BQ = AP$. That, together with $PQ = CP$, implies that $PB^2 + PQ^2 = BQ^2$. Now you can apply the inverse Pythagorean theorem to see $\angle BPQ = 90^\circ$. And don't forget that $\angle QPC$ is an angle of an equilateral triangle.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution of the problem. I think that it is self explaining, but if you have any question feel free to ask

hope this helps
[image]